# Linear Regression Functions in Cypher

Tags: neo4j, cypher

How can I find linear regression R-squared coefficient in cypher?

I want equivalent linear regression functions in Cypher as defined in [Oracle Database](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/functions139.htm#SQLRF00696):

```
REGR_R2(column_y, column_x)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may write your own [Java procedures in Neo4j](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/procedures/#user-defined-procedures) and call them from Cypher.

For regression function we can use apache commons [SimpleRegression](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/javadocs/api-3.3/org/apache/commons/math3/stat/regression/SimpleRegression.html) class.

The following code will create procedure named `regr` and it will return basic regression values for given X and Y properties.

You may call this procedure from Cypher as: `regr('MY_LABEL', 'Y', 'X')`

```
public class Regression {
@Context public GraphDatabaseService db;

// Result class
public static class Output {
    public double r2;
    public double avg_x;
    public double avg_y;
    public double slope;
    public Output(double r2, double avg_x, double avg_y, double slope){
        this.r2 = r2;
        this.avg_x = avg_x;
        this.avg_y = avg_y;
        this.slope = slope;
    }
}

@Procedure("regr")
public Stream<Output> regr(@Name("label") String label,
                             @Name("property_y") String y, @Name("property_x") String x ) {

    SimpleRegression regr = new SimpleRegression(false);
    double regr_avgx = 0;
    double regr_avgy = 0;
    int count = 0;

    try (ResourceIterator it = db.findNodes(Label.label(label))) {
        while (it.hasNext()) {
            Node node = (Node)it.next();
            if(node.hasProperty(x) && node.hasProperty(y))
            {
                Object prop_x = node.getProperty(x);
                Object prop_y = node.getProperty(y);

                regr_avgx += (double) ((Long)prop_x);
                regr_avgy += (double) ((Long)prop_y);
                regr.addData((double) ((Long)prop_x), (double) ((Long)prop_y));
                count++;
            }
        }
    }
    regr_avgx /= count;
    regr_avgy /= count;
    return Stream.of(new Output(regr.getRSquare(), regr_avgx, regr_avgy, regr.getSlope()));
}
}
```